# Arrays in HLSL?

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, shader, hlsl

I'm creating a game using XNA.
I have an terrain effect and I want to apply some points lights effects on it.

I'm pretty new to HLSL, and I want to do create an array in the effect file to instance all point lights positions, colors, intensity.

I don't know how to do that. This array will be then instanciated into my XNA code.

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd reconsider using XNA. It was abandoned by Microsoft last year. Look at OpenTK or MonoGame. (The latter will be more familiar as it's a reimplementation of the XNA framework).